# Multiple h2's styling. Can't style one H2 class

Tags: css

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/

Got a couple of h2's on the site. Need the image captions on main page have different styling. Gave them a different class and styled it. Doesn't work. What did i do wrong?
Used image widget and gave class in admin panel. Looking at the source code- it got the class.
css i used

```
h2.mainpagelist {
margin-top: -35px;
margin-left: 25px;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 13px !important;
color: #414040;
}
```

Comment: Specificity issue, `#one h2` is more specific than `h2.mainpagelist`

Comment: Remember that you should only use an ID once per page.